# Possible to infer keys of a nested object for argument type?

Tags: typescript

looking to type out a function and can't work out one arg.

I have multiple objects storing the array of roles allowed, which are then namespaced under one object by their route/screen for the helper function.

That function will take the key for the screen, and then which key under that specific permissions object to check:  Currently my union of `keyof typeof getAuthPermissions | keyof typeof getUserPermissions` returns ALL keys obviously when using the function like
`checkUserPermission('user', '<all-keys>')`
however, I want to infer just the keys from whichever screen is passed in to the function:
All relevant code:

```
const userGroups = ['Manager', 'Reporting', 'Payments', 'Support'] as const;
type UserGroup = typeof userGroups[number];

const getUserPermissions = {
    userControls: ['Manager', 'Support', 'Payments'],
    wallet: ['Manager', 'Support']
};
const getAuthPermissions = {
    logoutUser: ['Manager'],
    extendUserBonus: ['Manager', 'Support']
}
// ... a fair few more.
const allPermissions = {
    user: getUserPermissions,
    auth: getAuthPermissions
    // ...
}
type Screens = keyof typeof allPermissions;

function checkUserPermission(
    screen: Screens,
    userRoles: UserGroup[],
    // this should be the keys for whichever screen was passed in, (eg. keyof typeof allPermissions[typeof screen]?)
    permissionToCheck: keyof typeof getAuthPermissions | keyof typeof getUserPermissions // returns ALL keys. want to infer just from screen passed in
): boolean {
    for (const role of userRoles) {
        if (allPermissions[screen][permissionToCheck].includes(role)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is this possible? I know getting nested keys can be quite tricky, but I'm hoping that with inferring from the argument passed in that this should be possible?
Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to get the type at runtime, but typescript gets washed out at compile time. Most environments only execute javascript.

Comment: Yeah, I am seeing that as the main issue here, I was just hoping there may be a trick where we could hopefully infer with something like `checkUserPermission<T extends Screens>(screen: T, permissionToCheck: keyof typeof allPermissions[T]) {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that what you suggested, `checkUserPermission<T extends Screens>(screen: T, permissionToCheck: keyof typeof allPermissions[T]) {}` this works just fine.

However, you run into the type error where typescript is not sure that this expression: `allPermissions[screen][permissionToCheck]`, actually is an array, though I suppose it should in theory be able to figure it out.

If you do some nefarious looking typecasting you can get it all working:

```
function checkUserPermission<T extends Screens>(
    screen: T,
    userRoles: UserGroup[],
    permissionToCheck: keyof typeof allPermissions[T] 
): boolean {

    for (const role of userRoles) {
        const roles = allPermissions[screen][permissionToCheck] as unknown as UserGroup[]
        if (roles.includes(role)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

**Another alternative:**

Define getAuthPermissions and getUserPermissions differently, however, this loses out on some type specificity so use with caution:

```
const getUserPermissions: Record<string, UserGroup[]> = {
    userControls: ['Manager', 'Support', 'Payments'],
    wallet: ['Manager', 'Support'],
}

const getAuthPermissions: Record<string, UserGroup[]> = {
    logoutUser: ['Manager'],
    extendUserBonus: ['Manager', 'Support'],
}
```

Comment: Ah what an interesting way to get around. I'm not too familiar with the double cast here, especially with unknown, could you maybe give a short ELI5? I'm assuming the inner as unknown just describes that the particular key is unknown during run time, but that it will yield a UserGroup[]? Thank you though as this works well!

Comment: @joshuaaron the double cast is just to get around a failure of typescript type inferencing since the situation here is so complex. I think there's probably a neater solution because this one isn't really entirely type safe but it does get the job done.

Comment: @joshuaaron I posted another alternative if you care for it

Comment: thanks for the alternate solution, I think I'll stick with the original, though this is extra insight so definitely appreciate it. Thanks again